# How to tell if I won a challenge?

Tags: despicable-me-minion-rush

In the Andriod/iPhone app Minion Rush, how do you see who won the Facebook challenges?

I can challenge people each day just fine, but I never know who won, and I am never told I've been issued a challenge by someone else. One of the achievements is to win 25 challenges, but I don't even know if I've won one!

Comment: I made the [despicable-me-minion-rush](https://www.facebook.com/DespicableMeMinionRush) tag for you, because I *think* that's the actual name of the game. Let me know if it isn't the correct game. I also (accidentally) created a minion-rush tag, which should probably be a synonym for the proper despicable-me-minion-rush tag. Oops :D

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure your friends you challenge actually accepts the challenge.

You can challenge all your friends on facebook, even though they've ever played it.
I believe your problem is, none of your friends play the game.
This could also explain why you never receive any challanges.

You can always search for some forums, that are related to Minion Rush, and ask for people you can play with.
This is a common thing to do, for those who don't know anyone IRL, to get someone to play with and do challenges/achievements.

Answer (score 1):

It should say all of the results in the facebook challenges or whatever it is that you are using. Also you need to make sure that your friends accept the challenge before you try to see the results.